# How we can read a JSON file with Go Programming Language?

Tags: json, go

I'm working on a translation project on my Angular app. I already create all the different keys for that. I try now to use Go Programming Language to add some functionalities in my translation, to work quickly after.

I try to code a function in Go Programming Language in order to read an input user on the command line. I need to read this input file in order to know if there is missing key inside. This input user must be a JSON file. I have a problem with this function, is blocked at `functions.Check(err)`, in order to debug my function I displayed the different variable with `fmt.Printf(variable to display)`.
I call this function `readInput()` in my main function.

The `readInput()` function is the following :

```
    // this function is used to read the user's input on the command line
func readInput() string {
    // we create a reader
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    // we read the user's input
    answer, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    // we check if any errors have occured while reading
    functions.Check(err)
    // we trim the "\n" from the answer to only keep the string input by the user
    answer = strings.Trim(answer, "\n")
    return answer
}
```

In my main function I call `readInput()` for a specific command I created. This command line is usefull to update a JSON file and add a missing key automatically.

My `func main` is :

```
      func main() { 
        if os.Args[1] == "update-json-from-json" {

    fmt.Printf("please enter the name of the json file that will be used to 
    update the json file:") 
    jsonFile := readInput()

    fmt.Printf("please enter the ISO code of the locale for which you want to update the json file: ")
            // we read the user's input
            locale := readInput()
            // we launch the script
            scripts.AddMissingKeysToJsonFromJson(jsonFile, locale)
        }
```

I can give you the command line I use for this code `go run mis-t.go update-json-from-json`

Do you what I'm missing in my code please ?

Comment: go has the json package wich deals with json

Comment: @Pizzalord can you be more precise please ?

Comment: just google golang json the package and its documentation will be the first result. i do not know how you did not find it

Comment: I found this doc, but If I asked the question here with details, it's I need help to understand what I missed in this information @Pizzalord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that the file contains dynamic and unknown keys and values, and you cannot model them in your application. Then you can do something like:

```
func main() {
    if os.Args[1] == "update-json-from-json" {
        ...
        jsonFile := readInput()

        var jsonKeys interface{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(jsonFile, &jsonKeys)
        functions.Check(err)


        ...
    }
}
```

to load the contents into the `empty interface`, and then use the go reflection library (https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to iterate over the fields, find their names and values and update them according to your needs.

The alternative is to Unmarshal into a `map[string]string`, but that won't cope very well with nested JSON, whereas this might (but I haven't tested it).